# Dependencies and respective roles of the JavaScript libraries

Tags: javascript

SharePoint 2010 pages contain a bunch of JavaScript libraries (core.js, init.js, ribbon.js, etc.). Where can I find a high level description of their respective roles and dependencies?

The objective is to create lighter page templates by removing the unnecessary libraries. For example on some pages I don't need context menus, on others I don't need the ribbon, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found on the MSDN library this table that lists the namespaces in the ECMAScript object model and indicates the .js files in which they are defined:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538253.aspx